# Expresión regular para validar Cédula de Identidad de Costa Rica

Tags: javascript, regex, validación

Me toca validar una DNI de Costa Rica desde JavaScript, pero no me ha ido muy bien con el tema de expresiones regulares.

El formato de DNI que hay que validar es

```
1-0913-0259
```

Fuera de eso nada. He estado investigando como armar una expresión regular para validar eso, pero no doy con la solución.

Comment: Si necesitás validar más cosas (validar un form completo por ejemplo) donde metás distintos tipos de datos y no sólo la cédula podés utilizar un library de JS. Aquí hay una lista interesante: https://bashooka.com/coding/javascript-libraries-to-build-form-validation-like-a-boss/. Me gusta en especial jQuery Validator: https://jqueryvalidation.org/, en especial por el hecho de que se integra muy bien con jQuery.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**La Cédula de Identidad (o también DNI) de Costa Rica sigue el patrón:**

Inicio del texto, 1 dígito (del 1 al 9), guión, 4 dígitos, guión, 4 dígitos, fin del texto:

```
/^[1-9]-\d{4}-\d{4}$/
```

O si se quiere que los guiones sean opcionales:

```
/^[1-9]-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$/
```

---

**Cómo se conforma el número de cédula**

Según lo que leí en [Cédula de identidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9dula_de_identidad_(Costa_Rica)), se forma por `Provincia`-`Tomo`-`Asiento`.

- Provincia: Costa Rica tiene 7 provincias. Agregando los otros 2 valores posibles (nacionalizados y casos especiales), tenemos números del 1 al 9. El primer dígito se genera según esta tabla:

  ```
  Primer número   Provincia
  1               San José
  2               Alajuela
  3               Cartago
  4               Heredia
  5               Guanacaste
  6               Puntarenas
  7               Limón
  8               Nacionalizado o naturalizado
  9               Partida Especial de Nacimientos (casos especiales - Otros).
  ```
- Tomo: el tomo en que está inscrita en el Registro. Acá estoy asumiendo que cualquier número es válido (0000 a 9999).
- Asiento (o Folio): la anotación de su nacimiento. Si el asiento tuviese más de cuatro cifras se anotan solo las cuatro últimas. Por lo que podemos asegurar que es cualquier número entre 0000 y 9999.

Es decir que la única lógica posible para validar una cédula es que tenga los 9 dígitos. Los números de Cédula de Identidad son consecutivos (no tienen un dígito verificador).

Lo que sí podrías hacer, en caso de que te interese agregar una capa más de seguridad, es agregar el campo `Provincia de Nacimiento` en tu formulario, y validar que corresponda al primer dígito según la tabla de arriba.

---

**Validación**

Podemos validar de diferentes formas:

1. Código para validar que siga el formato `1-2345-6789` con:

   ```
   if ( /^[1-9]-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$/.test('1-2345-6789') ) {
       // cédula válida
   }
   ```

   ```js
   document.addEventListener( //Cuando se cargó la página
       'DOMContentLoaded',
       function (evt) {
           var btnValidar = document.getElementById('validar');
           btnValidar.addEventListener( //asociar el click a la validación
               'click',
               validarCedula
           );
       }
   );


   //VALIDACIÓN
   function validarCedula(evt) {
       var numCedula    = document.getElementById('cedula').value,
           resultado    = document.getElementById('resultado'),
           cedulaValida = /^[1-9]-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$/;
       
       if (cedulaValida.test(numCedula)) {
           resultado.innerText = 'Cédula Válida: ' + numCedula;
       } else {
           resultado.innerText = 'Cédula INVÁLIDA: ' + numCedula;
       }
   }
   ```

   ```css
   #cedula { width: 100%; }
   ```

   ```html
   <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Número de Cédula de Identidad">
   <input type="button" value="Validar" id="validar">
   <div id="resultado"/>
   ```
2. Dejando que el navegador valide con el atributo [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) (HTML5):

   ```
   <input type="text" pattern="[1-9]-?\d{4}-?\d{4}" required>
   ```

   ```html
   <form name="formulario" action="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwrb0.png">
       <input type="text" 
              id="cedula"
              name="cedula"
              pattern="[1-9]-?\d{4}-?\d{4}"
              required
              title="Formato: 1-2345-6789"
              placeholder="Cédula de Identidad"
              style="width:100%"
        >
        <input type="submit"
               value="Enviar"
        >
   </form>
   ```
3. O validar que también coincida el primer dígito con la provincia de nacimiento (con mensajes de validación para cada caso):

   ```
   if ( (m = /^([1-9])-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$/.exec(cedula)) && m[1] == provincia ) {
       //Cédula válida
   }
   ```

   ```js
   document.addEventListener( //Cuando se cargó la página
       'DOMContentLoaded',
       function (evt) {
       
           // Validar el form cuando se envia
           // (mostrar mensaje de error si es inválido)
           var btnEnviar = document.getElementById('enviar');
           btnEnviar.addEventListener(
               'click',
               validarForm
           );
           
           
           // Si se cambia la provincia -> esconder errores
           var inpProv = document.getElementById('provincia');
           inpProv.addEventListener(
               'input',
               esconderMensajeValidacion
           );
           // Si se cambia la cedula -> esconder errores
           var inpCedula = document.getElementById('cedula');
           inpCedula.addEventListener(
               'input',
               esconderMensajeValidacion
           );
           
           //Evitar enter como envío de form (lo hacemos por código)
           var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
           formulario.addEventListener(
               'submit',
               function(e){
                   e.preventDefault();
                   validarForm(e);
               }
           );
       }
   );


   // VALIDACIÓN
   function validarForm(event) {
       var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario'),
           inpProv    = document.getElementById('provincia'),
           inpCedula  = document.getElementById('cedula'),
           numCedula  = inpCedula.value;
       
       //Se seleccionó una provincia?
       if (!Number(inpProv.value) > 0) {
           inpProv.setCustomValidity(
               'Seleccione una Provincia de nacimiento'
           );
           formulario.reportValidity();
           return false;
       }
       
       //Se ingresó cédula?
       if (numCedula == '') {
           inpCedula.setCustomValidity(
               'La Cédula de Identidad no puede quedar vacía. Formato: 1-2345-6789'
           );
           formulario.reportValidity();
           return false;
       }
                   
       //Es válida?
       var cedulaValida = /^([1-9])-?(\d{4})-?(\d{4})$/,
           match;
       
       match = cedulaValida.exec(numCedula);
       if ( !match ) {
           inpCedula.setCustomValidity(
               'Cédula inválida. Formato: 1-2345-6789'
           );
           formulario.reportValidity();
           return false;
       }
                   
       //Corresponde a la provincia?
       // asignamos cada grupo que coincidió en una variable
       var provincia = match[1],
           tomo      = match[2],
           asiento   = match[3];
       
       if (provincia != inpProv.value) {
           inpCedula.setCustomValidity(
               'La Cédula no es válida para esa provincia. Formato: #-####-####'
           );
           formulario.reportValidity();
           return false;
       }
       
       //Alguna otra condición del input?
       if (!formulario.checkValidity()) {
           formulario.reportValidity();
           return false;
       }
       
       // Ok => ES VÁLIDO!!! (enviar)
       formulario.submit();
   }

   function esconderMensajeValidacion(evt) {
       var inpCedula = document.getElementById('cedula'),
           inpProv   = document.getElementById('provincia');
       // Esconder el error
       if (inpCedula.validity.customError) {
           inpCedula.setCustomValidity('');
       }
       if (inpProv.validity.customError) {
           inpProv.setCustomValidity('');
       }
   }

   // form.reportValidity() pseudo Polyfill para IE
   if ( !HTMLFormElement.prototype.reportValidity ) {
       HTMLFormElement.prototype.reportValidity = function() {
           var submitButtons = this.querySelectorAll('button, input[type=submit]');
           for (var i = 0; i < submitButtons.length; i++ ) {
               if ( submitButtons[i].type === "submit" ) {
                   submitButtons[i].click();
                   return;
               }
           }
           var submitButton = this.ownerDocument.createElement('input');
           submitButton.type = 'submit';
           submitButton.style.display = 'none';
           this.appendChild(submitButton);
           submitButton.click();
       }
   }
   ```

   ```css
   form > * { display: block; }
   ```

   ```html
   <form id="formulario" action="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwrb0.png">
       <select id="provincia" name="provincia">
           <option value="0">Provincia de nacimiento</option>
           <option value="1">San José</option>
           <option value="2">Alajuela</option>
           <option value="3">Cartago</option>
           <option value="4">Heredia</option>
           <option value="5">Guanacaste</option>
           <option value="6">Puntarenas</option>
           <option value="7">Limón</option>
           <option value="8">Nacionalizado o naturalizado</option>
           <option value="9">Partida especial de nacimiento</option>
       </select>
       <input type="text"
              id="cedula"
              name="cedula"
              required
              placeholder="Número de Cédula de Identidad">
       <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="enviar">
   </form>
   ```

---

Referencias:

- [Cédula de identidad (Costa Rica) - Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9dula_de_identidad_(Costa_Rica))
- [Documentos de Identificación (PDF) - Tribunal Supremo de Elecciones](http://www.tse.go.cr/pdf/fasciculos_capacitacion/documentos-de-identificacion.pdf)
- [Consulta de Personas (formulario online) - Tribunal Supremo de Elecciones](https://www.consulta.tse.go.cr/consulta_persona/menu.htm)

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias Mariano! Excelente aporte, sí fue un descuido mio.